# Generic List firstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq

I have a generic list and trying to get item based on value i.e.,

```
list.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.Key == key) // error 'T' does not contain definition for 'Key'
```

The generic type `T` having different base classes.

Comment: You need to create an interface that has a `Key` property on it, and have all of the classes you want to use this method implement it.

Comment: The 'Key' parameter will only be generated by linq when you perform a GroupBy().   Does your list come from a GroupBy() method?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of your List?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where your `T` is getting filled into `List<T>`, you could specify generic constraints on it to have an interface (or base class).

Interface:

```
interface IHasKey { string Key { get; } } // or some other type for `Key`
```

Generic constraint:

```
where T : IHasKey
```

Answer (score 2):

When using generic methods, you have to be sure your T has a property `Key`. That can be achieved with generic constraints. That can be either a base class or an interface:

```
interface IKeyedObject {
    string Key { get; };
}

class BaseWithKey : IKeyedObject {
    public string Key { get; set; };
}

class DerivedA : BaseWithKey {
}

class DerivedB : BaseWithKey {
}

class OtherWithKey : IKeyedObject {
    public string Key { get; set; };
}

//Solution with base class (will work with BaseWithKey, DerivedA, DerivedB)

T GetItemBaseClass<T>(List<T> list, string key)
    where T : BaseWithKey {

    return list.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.Key == key);
}

//Solution with interface (will work with all classes)

T GetItemInterface<T>(List<T> list, string key)
    where T : IKeyedObject {

    return list.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.Key == key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use Key while T is not specified and thus we do not know if T class contains any field/property Key.
On thing you can do is to use abstract class/interface or to try to cast u into the class that contains "Key" (assuming you are expecting some classes specificly). Some more details about your list and its items are needed for a more precise answer.
Hope it can help !